# How to make a maxium number of the position of the decimal point, in java

Tags: java

For example:

```
int getMax(int a) {
    return max;
}
```

> a : 1 --> max : 9, 
>  a : 2 --> max : 99,
>  a : 3 --> max :
>   999

and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: [`Math.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) is your friend..

Answer (score 2):

There are various options for this. Given that your method can only return `int`, there aren't very many options available, so you could just write:

```
private static final int[] results = { 9, 99, 999, 9999, ... };

public static int getMax(int a) {
    // TODO: Validate argument
    return results[a - 1];
}
```

Or you could loop:

```
public static int getMax(int a) {
    // TODO: Validate argument
    int result = 9;
    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
        result = result * 10 + 9;
    }
}
```

Or you could use `Math.pow()`, given that each result is 10<sup>a</sup> - 1:

```
public static int getMax(int a) {
    // TODO: Validate argument
    return (int) (Math.pow(10, a) - 1);
}
```